# Separating opacity of child from parent container? I want the child to not be effected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my container `overlay` to be at an opacity of 0.7, but to keep my child `text` to retain an opacity of 1.0.  If I try directly setting the opacity in the child element, nothing changes.  How would I change the `text` to have an opacity of 1.0, while keeping the `overlay` at 0.7?

CSS:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2a7de1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'karla';
}
```

HTML SAMPLE:

```
   <div class="contained1"> 
  <img class="resize" src="https://i.imgur.com/D2hr3Ma.jpg"> 
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Blog Illustrations</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/vYOKRzp?editors=1100

Comment: not sure if it works but have i tried to play with the z-index?

Comment: Might be easier to have a child `<div>` (sibling to `.text`) with the desired opacity and background color, that just expands to fill the parent.

Comment: Sorry, but could you give me an example of how to do this? I'm a bit new to coding still :/ Would I need to create another div tag inside of overlay and give it the same background color, but a full 1.0 opacity?